# Node.js: How To Keep Track of My API Usage?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My app as an API which I have no control of. I don't know which users use it, how many times, etc.

What's the best way of doing an analytics system to keep track of my API usage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Setup a fast database like Redis, then start doing simple request tracking. Improve on that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use harmony proxies to wrap all of your API objects to do some generic stats tracking by creating a general purpose proxy that intercepts function calls and forwards them to your actual api after recording the information that you need.

https://github.com/isaacs/node-proxy/

http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies